# solve this error "The import java.util.Random conflicts with a type defined in the same file"

Tags: java, eclipse

```
package amar;
import java.util.Random;

package amar;
import java.util.Random;
public class Random {
public static void main(String args[]){
    Random dice = new Random();
    int number;
    for(int counter=1;counter<=10;counter++)
    {
        number = 1+dice.nextInt(6);
        System.out.println(number +" ");
    }
}
}
```

Why am I getting an error while I am trying to run this in Eclipse Luna?

Answer (score 4):

You are importing a class named `Random` and *in* a class named `Random`. Change your own class' name.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because your class has the same name as the function. Try changing the name of your class.

Change Random in your class by RandomProgram by example.